# how to use set of strings as custom settings?

Tags: apex, customsetting

I have Set in my apex class as below

```
        Set<String> removeFields = new Set<String>{'isUpage','email','mobileno','owneremail','comments','Name','isApproved'};
```

I need to use these strings as custom settings because in future if i need to add any string to this list i can go through configuration instead of touching apex class

can anyone suggest me how to creates and get that custom setting values into set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply create a [list custom setting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_customsettings.htm) (for example with API name `CustomSettingName__c`) and enter the values in standard Name field. The name field is also unique which does not allow a duplicate value.

```
Map<String, CustomSettingName__c> mcs = CustomSettingName__c.getAll();
Set<String> removeFields = mcs.keySet();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a List Custom Setting or can use Custom Metadata and have all the values as records. Then when fetching the records, you can get the records from custom settings/custom metadata and convert those records into a `set<string>`

If you store these values as records in custom settings, where your name field will contain the value of `string`, then you can get those values as `set` directly using below method

```
Map<String, StringValues__c> stringValues = StringValues__c.getAll();
Set<String> removeFields = stringValues.keyset();
```